# Checking data in a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I am uploading a csv file and I want to check this file line by line using a python script to ensure that all the input id's match. This file contains object types, definitions and actions along with an input Id. When anyone enters the input Id and the path to their file on the command line next to the script, the script should run if the file exists and the input id matches the input Id in their file. if not I want to issue an error for them to check the id again? How can I do this?

This is the data and the expected output. I'm creating this along with a TIMESTAMP log to check that the information that was put in is correct. When the script starts it will go line by line and check that the input id is the right one so that no one fat fingers in the wrong id. Here is how the data looks:

```
Action  Object Type   Input ID
Add:    House Group   HG-Site-PIC
Add:    Service Team  HG-Site-PIC
Add:    Service       HG-Site-PIC
Modify
Modify
Modify
Delete
Delete
Delete
```

My code so far:

```
import csv
import sys
import os

def check_all(f):
    print f.read()

def print_a_line(line_count, f):
    print line_count, f.readline()

try:
    current_file = open(input_file)
    check_all(current_file)
except IOError, e:
    print '%s, please try again.' % e

ifile = open('file_name', "rb")
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
ofile = open('file_name', "wb")
writer = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter='\t', quotechar=' ',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)

ifile.close()
ofile.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Action Object Type Solution ID
Add House Group HG-Site-PIC
Add Service Team HG-Site-PIC
Add Service  HG-Site-PIC
Modify  
Modify  
Modify  
Delete  
Delete  
Delete  
This is the data and the expected output. I'm creating this along with a log to check that the information that was put in is correct

Comment: Do you need help parsing the command line or parsing the CSV?

Comment: what do you think `print f.read()` is going to do in check_all?

Comment: This is checking the file and reading all of the lines but it's not selecting the input id header. I want it to check this and bounce it against the input made in the command arg so that it can issue an error or proceed through the script

Comment: Where's the expected output?

Comment: It is here above the code

Comment: Above the code it says "Here is how the data looks:"

Comment: Do you see the layout? That is the data.

Comment: Isn't it obvious that I don't?

Comment: Yes sorry here is what is printing out when the file is run               Acttion      Object Type    Input ID                                       Add          House Group    HG-Site-PIC                                  Modify       Service        HG-Site-PIC                                  Delete       Site Group     HG-Site-PIC                                   This is just a few lines from the file but we need to check that the input id that is entered in the command argument matches the one in this file and then the script will run. Thanks